# AngularJS : ngRepeat in custom directive not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I created a custom directive including a `ng-repeat`. If I trigger a model update from the directive, the `ng-repeat` doesn't show data changes until something else happens in the view. I'm sure the data is correctly updated. This is the code:

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('myCTRL', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    //the 'model':
    $scope.data=[];
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        $scope.data.push({
            'val':i+1,
            'pos':i+1
        });

    $scope.directiveOptions = {
        changeData: function (from, to) {
            //here is the data update:
            var tmp= $scope.data[from].val;
            $scope.data[from].val =$scope.data[to].val;  
            $scope.data[to  ].val =tmp;
        }
    };

    $scope.revertData = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            $scope.data[i].pos = $scope.data[i].pos * -1;
    };
}]);
```

**View:**

```
<div ng-controller="myCTRL">
     <div id="container" ng-my-directive='directiveOptions'>
         <div ng-repeat="item in data | orderBy:'pos'" class="itemClass" >
             <div>
                 {{item.val}}
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-click="revertData()">revert</div>
</div>
```

**Directive:**

```
app.directive('ngMyDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: { 
            directiveOptions: '=ngMyDirective' 
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attr) {

            //...

            elem.on(
                'mouseup',
                function (e) {
                    // here I call the data change, but ng-repeat doesn't update
                    var from=2, to=3;
                    if (scope.directiveOptions.changeData){
                        scope.directiveOptions.changeData(from, to);
                    }
                }
            );
            //...
        }
    };
});
```

If I click on the `revertData` div I can see the data updated.
I have to force the `$apply()` at the end of the `changeData` or add an empty `ng-mouseover=""` in the `ng-repeat`, but I can't believe these are the best ways to do so, they seem only tricks.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

As @yarons proposed, using $evalAsync in the jQLite event, the data change involves the view update. but I not sure this is a best practice. I'm accessing a $scope variable from a directive nested ng-repeat. The directive implement a DOM manipulation that affects the model. Is this the best way to do so?

Comment: can you create a plunker for this?

Comment: @AdityaSethi here is the plunker with two possible solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/CF6ahi8g81NMhfV939l6?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your data changes on an event listener callback for `mouseup`.
In that case, your data changes outside the Angular digest loop, and thus not changed in your angular view.
Try to use

```
elem.on(
  'mouseup', function (e) {
     scope.$evalAsync(function() {
       var from=2, to=3;
       if (scope.directiveOptions.changeData){
         scope.directiveOptions.changeData(from, to);
       }
     });
   }
);
```